# what is wrong with my codes? difflib , sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, sklearn.metrics.pairwise import consine_similarity

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

[what should I download? this is a recommendation system using python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RXwA.png)

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a `typo` in the module name. Instead of `consine_similarity`, it should be `cosine_similarity`. Try changing the line to `from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Also if this don’t works, you should upload the code or make a functional example